# swift code not working in Xcode 7 - Cannot invoke initializer

Tags: ios, swift

I have a piece of code that was previously working in Swift 1.2 but not now in Swift 2. I tried to change it but I'm getting an error:[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uRgl1.png)

"Cannot invoke initializer...",

Also, here is the code. Could you please let me know what I am doing wrong?

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class RecordViewController: UIViewController {

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        var baseString : String = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask, true)[0] as String
        self.audioURL = "sound.m4a"
        var pathComponents = [baseString, self.audioURL]
        var audioNSURL = NSURL.fileURLWithPathComponents(pathComponents)
        var session = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
        do {
            try session.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord)
        } catch (_) {
        }
    //        session.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord, error: nil)

        var recordSettings: [NSObject : AnyObject] = Dictionary()
    //        recordSettings[AVFormatIDKey] = kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC
        recordSettings[AVFormatIDKey] = NSNumber(unsignedInt: kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC)
        recordSettings[AVSampleRateKey] = 44100.0
        recordSettings[AVNumberOfChannelsKey] = 2

    //        self.audioRecorder = AVAudioRecorder(URL: audioNSURL, settings: recordSettings, error: nil)
        self.audioRecorder = AVAudioRecorder()

        do {
            self.audioRecorder = try AVAudioRecorder(URL: audioNSURL!, settings: recordSettings)
        } catch (_) {

        }
        self.audioRecorder.meteringEnabled = true
        self.audioRecorder.prepareToRecord()

        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var recordButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var playButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var saveButton: UIBarButtonItem!

    var audioRecorder : AVAudioRecorder
    var audioURL = ""

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.playButton.enabled = false
        self.saveButton.enabled = false

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    @IBAction func cancelTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }

    @IBAction func saveTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
    }

    @IBAction func recordTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
        self.playButton.enabled = true
    }

    @IBAction func playTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type of `settings` parameter should be `[String: AnyObject]` since the initializer is declared following:

```
public init(URL url: NSURL, settings: [String : AnyObject]) throws
```

So one of the ways for fixing this is to change the type of `recordSettings` to be `[String: AnyObject]`.

```
var recordSettings: [String: AnyObject] = Dictionary()
```

Comment: Thanks to Katsumi this problem is solved. I changed from NSObject to String and the error is gone now. 
Also, thanks rmaddy for editing the post.